# Face Recognition Treasure Box Servo Issue

Tags: raspbian, gpio, camera

Im following a tutorial on adafruit, i have almost got it working but having some issue with the servo. i have followed the tutorial step by step, however when it comes to the configuration section, the servo doesnt work and gives me an error

[Face Recognition Treasure Box](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box?view=all#configuration)

above is the link to the tutorial, i will also attach an image of the issue.

if anyone can help me that would be great

thank you [image: image 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard release of RPIO does not support the Pi Zero, Pi2, or Pi3.

I guess you have one of those.

You will need to build RPIO from the github of RPIO version 2.

https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/tree/v2

I'd go to **that** github choose "Clone or download" and then "**Download ZIP**".

Then do the following on the Pi where you saved the ZIP.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
unzip RPIO-2.zip
cd RPIO-2/
sudo python setup.py install
sudo python3 setup.py install
```